# createQuery(HQL) retorna NullPointerException ao tentar realizar LEFT OUTER JOIN

Tags: java, hibernate, query, join, hql

Fala pessoal,

estou com um problema ao tentar executar um HQL na minha aplicação.

A HQL é basicamente essa:

```
select c.id, c.solicitante from <mypackage>.Exame c
LEFT OUTER JOIN <mypackage>.Profissional prof
```

Código java:

```
hql = "select c.id, c.solicitante from <mypackage>.Exame c LEFT OUTER JOIN <mypackage>.Profissional prof";
session = HibernateUtil.currentSession();
Query query = session.createQuery(hql);//o erro acontece aqui
```

e a exception é a seguinte:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at <mypackage>.DaoBase.executarQuery(DaoBase.java:129)
at <mypackage>.RelatoriosBean.gerarRelatorio(RelatoriosBean.java:73)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invokeMethod(BeanELResolver.java:779)
at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:528)
at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:257)
at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:248)
at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:302)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
at javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:148)
```

Não sou um expert em HQL mas sei que não é necessário explicitar uma clausula **WITH** após o **JOIN**.

Eu realmente não sei o que pode ser. Isso acontece com qualquer relacionamento que eu tenho na minha classe. Como é uma ferramenta de relatórios, caso eu selecione apenas campos de tipo primitivo (ex.: String, Integer, etc.) o HQL é executado normalmente.

E sim, pesquisei bastante sobre como desenvolver o HQL, procurei também se alguem já se deparou com esse problema mas até agora nenhuma solução proposta me ajudou...

Desde já agradeço qualquer ajuda!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

na verdade a query deve ser da seguinte maneira:

```
select c.id, c.solicitante from <mypackage>.Exame c LEFT OUTER JOIN c.solicitante prof
```

ou seja, utilizar o nome do atributo ao invés do nome da classe (sendo **c.solicitante** o nome do atributo dentro da classe `<mypackage>.Exame`)

Enfim, é isso!

Comment: Ha, demorei pra encontrar essa no hql original hehe. Aliás, acho que não é necessário esse `<mypackage>` ai também não hein? Se a entidade estiver mapeada, acredito que vai deboa. Pelo menos eu nunca usei.

Comment: @GustavoCinque realmente não era necessário. Desculpe a demora na resposta, as coisas estavam bem pesadas na época hahahah

Comment: kkk Nevermind. Sei como é.